# How to avoid WPF window reduces its dimension

Tags: wpf, xaml, window, size

I read a few post but I can't fix this problem.

I have a `Grid` defined as follow:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   ...
```

Where in the first row I want a `Border` with a `TextBlock` inside. I need that the `Border` has always the same size without be influenced from the `TextBlock`.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource StandardBorderColor}" BorderThickness="2" Margin="15,10,15,10"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Name="TextBlock" Margin="20, 15, 20, 20"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="{DynamicResource StandardForegroundColor}" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Testo}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
</Grid>
```

Do you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**Update:**

[image: Initial condition]

[image: Second condition]

**Solution:**

I found this as solution:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <GroupBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  Margin="15, 10, 15, 10" Header="Avvisi">
            <TextBox x:Name="TextBlock" FontSize="16" 
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                     TextAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Testo}" Style="{DynamicResource TxtBoxStyle}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                     BorderBrush="Transparent" IsReadOnly="True" />
        </GroupBox>
   ...
```

Comment: Why ur `Border` will change its size ? Assign some width to `Border`, or `ColumnDefinition`.

Comment: First of all, your textblock is not inside the border, but on top of it. Second, how about specifying the width and height ?

Comment: I would avoid to set specific width because I want the window is correctly shown with all the kind of screen.

Comment: If you don't want your grid's column width to fit its content, change `auto` to `*`

Comment: @Bolu Even if Width is set as "*" it doesn't work.

Comment: Grab your screen size, then set it as min width and height.

Comment: @ctt_it don't forget you need to change both outer grid and inner grid.. or just delete both `ColumnDefinitions`, as the default value will just give what you wanted.

Comment: @Bolu yes, sure. It was what I did. In the updated code version you can find my solution. I used your suggestion.

Comment: @ctt_it, good for you. post it as an answer then.

Comment: thanks for the help!